# How to allow full access multiple url segments in Larvel5.3.19

Tags: authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-middleware, illuminate-container

I'm create file upload with CKeditor4.5 with Larvel5.3.19 this task I want to know is it possible to allow Larvel  url for fully accessing multiple url segments example.

http://web.dev/browser/browse.php?CKEditor=textarea&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en

RO

http://web.dev/browser/imgupload/CKEditor/textarea2/CKEditorFuncNum/1/langCode/en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first options you can access the parameters using `Illuminate\Http\Request` [Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#retrieving-input) in your controller method.

```
$textarea = $request->input('textarea');
```

For the second option you can do

```
Route::get(' browser/imgupload/CKEditor/{fields}', ['as'=>'cke.upload','uses'=>'CKEController@imgUpload'])
        ->where('fields', '.*');
```

You can then use `preg_split("#/#", $fields)` to access the parameters in your controller method.